# Swifui: MacOS App: Fetching Core Data in ContentView OK, but how to use the result from AppDelegate?

Tags: swiftui, observableobject, environmentobject

With Xcode 11.6 (11E708), SwiftUI, for a MacOS app, I have data generated in the `ContentView.swift`. But I cannot use those data inside the `AppDelegate.swift`:

Build Succeeded but the `print(contentView.order.item)` (please see below) produce this message:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type Order found. A
> View.environmentObject(_:) for Order may be missing as an ancestor of
> this view.

What am I missing?

**In ContentView.swift:**

```
import SwiftUI
public class Order: ObservableObject {
    @Published var item = "Hello"
}
...
@EnvironmentObject var order: Order
...
```

**In AppDelegate.swift:**

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    ... 
    let contentView = ContentView()
    print(contentView.order.item)
    ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to inject `Order` to the environment if it will be used as an `@EnvironmentObject`:

```
let order = Order() // declare it once
let contentView = ContentView().environmentObject(order) // inject to the environment
```